# Declaring a HMODULE throws an exception at runtime

Tags: c++, dll, handle, loadlibrary

I'm writing a C++ DLL that loads another DLL during one of its functions. However, when I try to run it, it crashes when I first declare my HMODULE variable, even before I try calling LoadLibrary.

Specifically, my code is:

```
HMODULE my_hmod;
my_hmod = LoadLibrary("C:\\path_to_dll");
```

it crashes between those two lines (I've stepped through it and noticed it crashes in "ostream" if that's helpful).

The exception is as follows:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00a7392d (d3d9.dll) in PixelMotionBlur.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Any help would be appreciated! I'll post more code/debugging info if needed.

**EDIT:** here's the actual function code:

```
    D3D9Wrapper::IDirect3D9* WINAPI Direct3DCreate9(UINT Version)
{
    InitializeDLL();
    HMODULE hD3D;
    if(IsWow64())
    {
        hD3D = LoadLibrary("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\d3d9.dll");
    }
    else
    {
        hD3D = LoadLibrary(g_Globals.RealD3D9DLL.CString());
    }

    if( hD3D == NULL )
    {
        g_Globals.ErrorFile() << "LoadLibrary on d3d9.dll failed\n";
        return NULL;
    }

    D3D9Wrapper::D3DCREATE pCreate = (D3D9Wrapper::D3DCREATE)GetProcAddress(hD3D, _T("Direct3DCreate9"));
    if( pCreate == NULL )
    {
        g_Globals.ErrorFile() << "coud not find Direct3DCreate9 in d3d9.dll\n";
        return NULL;
    }

    D3D9Base::LPDIRECT3D9 pD3D = pCreate(D3D_SDK_VERSION);
    if( pD3D == NULL )
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    //return (D3D9Wrapper::IDirect3D9*)pD3D;
    return D3D9Wrapper::IDirect3D9::GetDirect3D(pD3D);
}
```

In case it helps, the function of this DLL (most is not actually my code but used with permission) is to hook all calls to d3d9.dll by placing a new dll also named d3d9 in the folder with the target .exe (right now I'm testing it with the sample .exes from the Direct X 9 sdk).

EDIT 2: here's the full disassembly of the function:

```
    D3D9Wrapper::IDirect3D9* WINAPI Direct3DCreate9(UINT Version)
{
008B6960  push        ebp  
008B6961  mov         ebp,esp  
008B6963  and         esp,0FFFFFFF8h  
008B6966  sub         esp,8  
    InitializeDLL();
008B6969  cmp         byte ptr [g_Globals (8CAC40h)],0  
008B6970  push        esi  
008B6971  push        edi  
008B6972  jne         Direct3DCreate9+48h (8B69A8h)  
008B6974  mov         edi,offset g_Globals (8CAC40h)  
008B6979  call        Globals::Init (8B6A80h)  
008B697E  mov         eax,dword ptr [g_Globals+34h (8CAC74h)]  
008B6983  push        8C0D98h  
008B6988  push        eax  
008B6989  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (8938F0h)  
008B698E  call        dword ptr [__imp_D3D9CallbackInitialize (8B81A4h)]  
008B6994  mov         ecx,dword ptr [g_Globals+34h (8CAC74h)]  
008B699A  push        8C0DB0h  
008B699F  push        ecx  
008B69A0  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (8938F0h)  
008B69A5  add         esp,10h  
    HMODULE hD3D;
    if(IsWow64())
008B69A8  push        8C0E60h  
008B69AD  push        8C0E70h  
008B69B2  mov         dword ptr [esp+14h],0  
008B69BA  call        dword ptr [__imp__GetModuleHandleA@4 (8B80D0h)]  
008B69C0  mov         edi,dword ptr [__imp__GetProcAddress@8 (8B80C4h)]  
008B69C6  push        eax  
008B69C7  call        edi  
008B69C9  mov         esi,eax  
008B69CB  test        esi,esi  
008B69CD  je          Direct3DCreate9+94h (8B69F4h)  
008B69CF  lea         edx,[esp+0Ch]  
008B69D3  push        edx  
008B69D4  call        dword ptr [__imp__GetCurrentProcess@0 (8B80B8h)]  
008B69DA  push        eax  
008B69DB  call        esi  
008B69DD  test        eax,eax  
008B69DF  jne         Direct3DCreate9+94h (8B69F4h)  
008B69E1  mov         eax,dword ptr [g_Globals+3Ch (8CAC7Ch)]  
008B69E6  push        8C0E7Ch  
008B69EB  push        eax  
008B69EC  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (8938F0h)  
008B69F1  add         esp,8  
008B69F4  cmp         dword ptr [esp+0Ch],0  
008B69F9  je          Direct3DCreate9+0A2h (8B6A02h)  
    {
        hD3D = LoadLibrary("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\d3d9.dll");
008B69FB  push        8C0E98h  
    }
    else
008B6A00  jmp         Direct3DCreate9+0B1h (8B6A11h)  
    {
        hD3D = LoadLibrary(g_Globals.RealD3D9DLL.CString());
008B6A02  mov         eax,dword ptr [g_Globals+1Ch (8CAC5Ch)]  
008B6A07  test        eax,eax  
008B6A09  jne         Direct3DCreate9+0B0h (8B6A10h)  
008B6A0B  mov         eax,offset g_Globals+1Ch (8CAC5Ch)  
008B6A10  push        eax  
008B6A11  call        dword ptr [__imp__LoadLibraryA@4 (8B80CCh)]  
    }

    if( hD3D == NULL )
008B6A17  test        eax,eax  
008B6A19  jne         Direct3DCreate9+0D9h (8B6A39h)  
    {
        g_Globals.ErrorFile() << "LoadLibrary on d3d9.dll failed\n";
008B6A1B  mov         ecx,dword ptr [g_Globals+3Ch (8CAC7Ch)]  
008B6A21  push        8C0EB8h  
008B6A26  push        ecx  
008B6A27  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (8938F0h)  
008B6A2C  add         esp,8  
        return NULL;
008B6A2F  xor         eax,eax  
}
008B6A31  pop         edi  
008B6A32  pop         esi  
008B6A33  mov         esp,ebp  
008B6A35  pop         ebp  
008B6A36  ret         4  
    }
    D3D9Wrapper::D3DCREATE pCreate = (D3D9Wrapper::D3DCREATE)GetProcAddress(hD3D, _T("Direct3DCreate9"));
008B6A39  push        8C0ED8h  
008B6A3E  push        eax  
008B6A3F  call        edi  
    if( pCreate == NULL )
008B6A41  test        eax,eax  
008B6A43  jne         Direct3DCreate9+103h (8B6A63h)  
    {
        g_Globals.ErrorFile() << "coud not find Direct3DCreate9 in d3d9.dll\n";
008B6A45  mov         edx,dword ptr [g_Globals+3Ch (8CAC7Ch)]  
008B6A4B  push        8C0EE8h  
008B6A50  push        edx  
008B6A51  call        std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (8938F0h)  
008B6A56  add         esp,8  
        return NULL;
008B6A59  xor         eax,eax  
}
008B6A5B  pop         edi  
008B6A5C  pop         esi  
008B6A5D  mov         esp,ebp  
008B6A5F  pop         ebp  
008B6A60  ret         4  
    }
```

**EDIT 3:** the call stack as of the thrown exception:

```
>   d3d9.dll!std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> > & _Ostr, const char * _Val)  Line 773 + 0x3 bytes    C++
    d3d9.dll!InitializeDLL()  Line 70 + 0x15 bytes  C++
    d3d9.dll!Direct3DCreate9(unsigned int Version)  Line 141    C++
    PixelMotionBlur.exe!DXUT_Dynamic_Direct3DCreate9(unsigned int SDKVersion)  Line 714 + 0xc bytes C++
    PixelMotionBlur.exe!DXUTDelayLoadD3D9()  Line 2706 + 0xa bytes  C++
    PixelMotionBlur.exe!DXUTGetD3D9Object()  Line 712 + 0x23 bytes  C++
    PixelMotionBlur.exe!CD3D9Enumeration::Enumerate(bool (_D3DCAPS9 *, _D3DFORMAT, _D3DFORMAT, bool, void *)* IsD3D9DeviceAcceptableFunc, void * pIsD3D9DeviceAcceptableFuncUserContext)  Line 309 + 0x5 bytes  C++
    PixelMotionBlur.exe!DXUTGetD3D9Enumeration(bool bForceEnumerate)  Line 255  C++
    PixelMotionBlur.exe!DXUTFindValidDeviceSettings(DXUTDeviceSettings * pOut, DXUTDeviceSettings * pIn, DXUTMatchOptions * pMatchOptions)  Line 174    C++
    PixelMotionBlur.exe!DXUTCreateDevice(bool bWindowed, int nSuggestedWidth, int nSuggestedHeight)  Line 2010 + 0x17 bytes C++
    PixelMotionBlur.exe!wWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * __formal, HINSTANCE__ * __formal, HINSTANCE__ * __formal, HINSTANCE__ * __formal)  Line 207  C++
    PixelMotionBlur.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 547 + 0x2c bytes  C
    PixelMotionBlur.exe!wWinMainCRTStartup()  Line 371  C
    kernel32.dll!75e1339a()     
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for kernel32.dll]  
    ntdll.dll!77829ed2()    
    ntdll.dll!77829ea5()
```

Comment: It's not crashing where you think it's crashing.

Comment: That's not the crash.  Are you compiling with optimizations enabled?  If so, the debugger is lying to you about where the crash is.  Post more code, and post the disassembly around that address as well.

Comment: Is the other dll doing anything in its DllMain?

Comment: I'm using the VS 2010 compiler, which I'm quite new to -- I think its not optimized since I turned off "Whole Program Optimization" in the project config properties. Are there other spot where VS sneaks in compilation optimizations?

Comment: @Zac the other dll (i.e. the one I'm trying to load) definitely isn't having its main called, as the error persists even without the loadlibrary call :-/

Comment: Are you building it with the Debug project configuration?

Comment: Apparently I'm using the Active(Release) configuration. I take it I should be using the Debug config instead?

Comment: Ok, the HMODULE declaration is officially not the problem; I moved it into a earlier called function of the dll and it works fine, but then crashes shortly after. Any ideas as to how I can go about debugging this? :(

Comment: The HMODULE declaration doesn't actually do anything, since it's not being assigned anything. As you can see in the assembly dump, there is no assembly code between it and the IsWin64 call. Post the call stack from where the access violation occurs.

Comment: Posted the call stack -- the top is where the exception occurred

Comment: The error is in InitializeDLL. See my answer.

Comment: Did you create your own DLL named "d3d9.dll" with an InitializeDll() function?  That's not going to work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the call stack, the error is in the InitializeDLL function. Can't really say for sure without seeing the source code of that function, but since it's a NULL pointer exception via std::ostream, I would bet that you're trying to send a NULL string to std::cout or some such.

Check line 70 of the source file that InitializeDLL is in. If you don't see the problem, post the code from InintializeDLL.

Comment: You sir, are truly magical. That was precisely what was going wrong, and despite a complete misdirection on my part, you still managed to find it. Bravo, and I apologize to everyone that I hadn't properly localized my problem.

Comment: Also, should I delete this question since the problem wasn't at all to do with HMODULE?

Comment: Leave the question, as the road to the resolution might prove useful to somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running & building the debug version of your program.  In VS2010 make sure you have the "Debug" build configuration selected & in the debugger menu make sure you are breaking on the throw of any C++ exceptions.

You are correct - I'm able to do the following just fine.

```
HMODULE hD3D = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\d3d9.dll");
```

Comment: I just tried changing the configuration to Debug and the problem persists. Do the different configuration names really matter over and above the configuration property presets their associated with?

Comment: Also, I tried putting "HMODULE hD3D = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\d3d9.dll");" in another part of my dll and it loads fine -- and then crashes in the same place irregardless :(

Comment: certainly the properties are the important pieces, the debug configuration should hopefully have all optimization turned off & debug checks turned on.  Whats the call stack when it crashes?

Comment: The fact that it is "crashing in ostream" is an important clue.